# PhD courses instructs language in Germany

Tags: phd, germany

What's the main language used in PhD courses in Germany for most of the fields ? CS, chemistry...

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Germany, there usually are no PhD "courses", except for some specialized programs ("Graduiertenkolleg"), which are still in the minority.

Most PhD students conduct research from day 1, under the supervision of a specific advisor. The language of communication will depend on the advisor and the student. Working with international students is not an issue for most advisors.

Comment: PhD students might follow relevant BSc and MSc courses though. These are instructed in whatever language the instructor prefers. Often, this is German.

Comment: One might add that the reason that PhD students in Germany usually don't take (many) courses is that in virtually all cases an MSc (or equivalent) is required before starting the PhD.

Comment: @cheersmate Indeed, although many departments have a "fast-track" program to go from BSc to PhD without MSc (in case of which they might need to attend some MSc courses). But that's still the less typical option by far.

Comment: @Mark In these cases, there probably will be accommodations for international PhD students. The main message here is that lack of German language proficiency is usually not a limiting factor for being able to complete a PhD in Germany.

Comment: @Mark "These are instructed in whatever language the instructor prefers": This is rather unlikely in the BSc. There's probably a main language which students can demand. Also in the MSc, there are several places which have changed the master's programme to English, in courses will be taught all in English (or at least students can demand it).

Comment: @lighthousekeeper One might add to the answer that even in the case of structured PhD programmes, there is usually a lot of flexibility in which courses to attend, and there's always courses offered in english.

Comment: @user151413: I know of several such programs which are officially to be held in english. In practise, the instructor sometimes asks the audience for their preferred language and sometimes says "I want to do this in German. If you don't speak German, learn it." even though the course is announced as English. And more often then not, there is no person you can complain to de facto.

Comment: @user111388 Sounds like the stuff that formal complaints are made of. I never heard of a comparable case.

Comment: @user111388 What field would that be?  I agree I never heard of a comparable case in math or physics.  Most people lecture by default in English, or would only do it in German if everyone was fine with it.  In fact, my experience is that even most German-speaking students prefer to take their exam in English after an English lecture. But it might depend on the culture of the place or the subject.

Comment: @user151413: I have seen it only twice in maths (and one time where a prof every lesson from the middle of the course just forgot he wanted to lecture in English- after some time, students just gave up reminding him and dropped the course). From friends, I heard it's common in subjects like law, politics studies etc. - most of the time in courses where - the prof is older/ politically well-connected and - where there are so many students that people just want to get rid of students (sometimes with strange exam questions "On what page in the textbook was this information?").

Comment: @user111388 Law, politics, etc. is a different story - I find it hard to see how you would teach German law in English.  The role of language is an entirely different one there.

Comment: @user151413: In this case, I think the official homepage should not say "program offered in English" if a prof can say in the first lessson "I don't do English".

Comment: @user111388 Such a case surely sucks for affected MSc students. In the context of this question, it's maybe not that relevant. It seems unlikely that an international student would sign up for a PhD in German law without speaking German, only to be sent by his advisor to a colleague who tends to give his courses in German.

Comment: @user111388 That shouldn't be the case, indeed. One issue might be that, while professors in Germany are obliged to do a certain amount of teaching, it is rather unclear whether they can be forced to do a specific *type* of teaching (i.e. which subject, but certainly also which teaching language).  (It was even debated whether the teaching duty includes teaching online.)  So there might be no way for the university to force those colleagues to teach in German.  Then again, it would be wisest to not assign them to those courses.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper: I agree it's probably not relevant to the question. My goal was to answer user151413's question to Mark.